# Instatiate Realm Object from string in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, realm

I would like to know if it is possible to instantiate a realm object based on a string that is the class name of the realm object but without knowing what that string will be until it is provided.

For example:

```
for(_, object) in json["AllObjects"]{
    let objectType = self.getRealmObjectBasedOnString(type: className, params: object.stringValue)
    self.objectList.append(objectType)
}
```

Here I go through a json that I get and want to create a realm object from each json object in the array. The problem is that this method will be called several times and each time the only thing that will change is the className variable. So I would like to keep this logic in only one method instead of creating several methods with same logic or a huge and complicated if else that determines the realm object to be created.

Here is getRealmObjectBasedOnString

```
func getRealmObjectBasedOnString(type: String, params: String) -> Object{
    switch type {
    case "classA":
        return ClassA(JSONString: params)!
    case "classB":
        return ClassB(JSONString: params)!
    default:
        return DefaultClass(JSONString: params)!
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this does not work and whether it is possible to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSClassFromString` to get Realm object type from string, but keep in mind that Swift uses modules for nemespacing, so you'll need to add your app's module name before your class name.

```
guard let objectType = NSClassFromString("YourAppModuleName.\(json["className")") else {
    // handle unexpected class here
}

let objectList = realm.objects(objectType)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wanted to accomplish. I don't to get the realm objects of that type I already have, I want to create a new one. So if I send a string "ClassA" I wanna get back an instance of ClassA object which I can then save into realm.

Comment: Then you just need to use [`create(_:value:update:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.5.1/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createuRxCS_6ObjectrFTMx5valueP_6updateSb_x)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I just needed to create a json object again from the one sent in the for loop and that's it. Thank you :D